# How to set a timeout to abort an $http.get() inside a factory or service?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have the following method `getData(url)` in a my **factory** which uses    `$http.get(url)` to get data from an URL

```
angular
  .module('az-app')
  .factory('WebServiceFactory', function ($http, $q) {

   var WebServiceFactory = this;


   WebServiceFactory.getData = function (url) {

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.get(url)
        .then(
        function (response) {

          deferred.resolve({
            data: response
          });

        }, function (rejected) {

          deferred.reject({
            data: rejected
          });
        }
      );
      //Promise to be returned
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

It works fine but I need to abort the http.get and/or reject the promise so I can display an error message from my **controller** which has this method:

```
var getSpecialties = function (type) {
  doctorsCtrl.showLoading();

  var url = "example.com";

  WebServiceFactory.getData(url)
    .then(
    function (result) {
      doctorsCtrl.hideLoading();


      var specialtiesArray = result.data.data;

      StorageFactory.specialties = specialtiesArray;
      doctorsCtrl.specialties = StorageFactory.specialties

      //I WANT TO TRIGGER THIS REJECTED FUNCTION when timeout time is finished
    }, function (rejected) {
      doctorsCtrl.hideLoading();
      doctorsCtrl.showAlert();
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The service `$http` accepts, in the config object, a `timeout` property that answers to what you need. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), especially the part about the `config` object:

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

Also, notice that you're using promises in an inefficient way. The following is a ***promise antipattern***:

> ```
> WebServiceFactory.getData = function (url) {
>
>  var deferred = $q.defer();
>
>  $http.get(url)
>    .then(
>    function (response) {
>
>      deferred.resolve(...);
>
>    }, function (rejected) {
>
>      deferred.reject(...);
>    }
>  );
>  //Promise to be returned
>  return deferred.promise;
> }
> ```

You could have simply:

```
WebServiceFactory.getData = function (url) {
    return $http.get(url);
}
```

With a timeout of 3 seconds it would be:

**Service:**

```
WebServiceFactory.getData = function (url) {
    return $http.get(url, {timeout: 3000});  // <-- timeout applies ONLY for this call
}
```

**Controller:**

```
WebServiceFactory.getData(url).then(
    function (result) {
      doctorsCtrl.hideLoading();
      doctorsCtrl.specialties = StorageFactory.specialties = result.data;
    }, function (rejected) {
      doctorsCtrl.hideLoading();
      doctorsCtrl.showAlert();
    }
  );
```

Notice also that you're calling `hideLoading` both in case of *success* and *error*. You can call it once, in a chained *finally* handler:

```
// ...
.finally(function () {
    doctorsCtrl.hideLoading();
}
```

Comment: Hi michael, thanks for answer but I don't want to use it in config (I'm familiar with the httprovider way) as I want a timeout of 10 secs for http.get and a timeout of 60 secs for http.post methods, to my understanding If I set it in config then it is global. So I wanted an example of timeout with this http.get then I would figure it out for http.post

Comment: It won't make it global at all, you set it in the configuration object of *that* specific call to `$http.get`. I've completed the answer with your code, hoping it's more clear.

Comment: so I'm trying to test it with `WebServiceFactory.getD = function (url) {
      return $http.get(url, {timeout: 1000});
    }`, but how can I trigger   `function (rejected) {` at controller if the promise hasn't been resolved after 1 second have passed? I'm inserting some console.log() to see what the answer is and even though it seems that it's taking longer than 1 sec, it doesn't seem to be triggering the rejected function in controller

Comment: Hm, I don't see what's wrong as this is the way to do. Will make a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: for example if I put `WebServiceFactory.getD = function (url) { return $http.get(url, {timeout: 10});    }`  notice the 10 at timeout, shouldn't this be so short to trigger the reject funciton at controller since I'm making an API call that it seems its taking at least 2 secs, surely more than 1 sec. But it's not triggering the reject function :(

Comment: Should make the timeout resolved, and therefore trigger the *error* callback. I've made you a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/7a6jvbp7/)

Comment: Hi Mike this seems to be working please give me sometime to confirm if not I'll be back :)

Comment: at least I got it working, and you went the extra mile with the finally function so I don't have to repeat code and I can comply with DRY principle, you rock!!! thanks for all the help and patience!! will accept your answer and upvote :)

Comment: You're welcome! :) At the beginning promises might be a bit hard to harness but once you understand you start liking it:)

Comment: Hi, IMHO resolve the data in the service (like @Jeka was doing) is a better practice, the controller doesn't need to know the respective response's object child containing the actual data.